# JOIN / LEFT JOIN conflict in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a tricky query. I need to select all recent versions of 2 types of members of administrator groups. Here is the query:

```
SELECT refGroup.*
FROM tblSystemAdministratorGroups refGroup
JOIN tblGroup refMem ON refGroup.AttributeValue = refMem.ObjectUID
```

This query will return all the administrator groups. The next step will be getting the members of these groups. Since I have 2 types of memberships (Explicit, Computed), I will have to use a `LEFT JOIN` to make sure that I am not excluding any rows.

```
SELECT refGroup.*
FROM tblSystemAdministratorGroups refGroup
-- The JOIN bellow can be excluded but it is here just to clarify the architecture
JOIN tblGroup refMem ON refGroup.AttributeValue = refMem.ObjectUID
LEFT JOIN tblGroup_ComputedMember cm ON refMem.ObjectUID = cm.GroupObjectID
LEFT JOIN tblGroup_ExplicitMember em ON refMem.ObjectUID = em.GroupObjectID
```

The last piece in the puzzle is to get the latest version of each member. For that I will have to use `JOIN` to exclude older versions:

```
JOIN (
    SELECT MAX([ID]) MaxId 
    FROM [OmadaReporting].[dbo].tblGroup_ComputedMember 
    GROUP BY ObjectID  
) MostRecentCM ON MostRecentCM.MaxId = cm.Id
```

and

```
JOIN (
    SELECT MAX([ID]) MaxId 
    FROM [OmadaReporting].[dbo].tblGroup_ExplicitMember 
    GROUP BY ObjectID  
) MostRecentEM ON MostRecentEM.MaxId = em.Id
```

The full query will be:

```
SELECT refGroup.*
FROM tblSystemAdministratorGroups refGroup
JOIN tblGroup refMem ON refGroup.AttributeValue = refMem.ObjectUID
LEFT JOIN tblGroup_ComputedMember cm ON refMem.ObjectUID = cm.GroupObjectID
JOIN (
    SELECT MAX([ID]) MaxId 
    FROM [OmadaReporting].[dbo].tblGroup_ComputedMember 
    GROUP BY ObjectID  
) MostRecentCM ON MostRecentCM.MaxId = cm.Id
LEFT JOIN tblGroup_ExplicitMember em ON refMem.ObjectUID = em.GroupObjectID
JOIN (
    SELECT MAX([ID]) MaxId 
    FROM [OmadaReporting].[dbo].tblGroup_ExplicitMember 
    GROUP BY ObjectID  
) MostRecentEM ON MostRecentEM.MaxId = em.Id
```

The issue is clear: The 2 `JOIN` to exclude old versions are also applied to the select statement and clearly no rows are returned. What would be the best solution to escape such situation and to return the intended values?

Comment: Moslem means one who oppresses, btw, as opposed to muslim, which means one who submits, to God.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT refGroup.*
FROM tblSystemAdministratorGroups refGroup
JOIN tblGroup refMem ON refGroup.AttributeValue = refMem.ObjectUID
LEFT JOIN (
    select GroupObjectID, ID, max(ID) over (partition by ObjectID) as maxID
    from tblGroup_ComputedMember
) cm ON refMem.ObjectUID = cm.GroupObjectID and cm.ID = cm.maxID
LEFT JOIN (
    select GroupObjectID, ID, max(ID) over (partition by ObjectID) as maxID
    from tblGroup_ExplicitMember
) em ON refMem.ObjectUID = em.GroupObjectID and em.ID = em.maxID
where cm.ID = cm.MaxID
```

Answer (score 2):

What about using LEFT join in your last two joins?

```
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT MAX([ID]) MaxId 
    FROM [OmadaReporting].[dbo].tblGroup_ComputedMember 
    GROUP BY ObjectID  
) MostRecentCM ON MostRecentCM.MaxId = cm.Id
```

And then in Where clause filter values as:

```
WHERE MostRecentCM.MaxId IS NOT NULL 
      OR
      MostRecentEM.MaxId IS NOT NULL
```